# Spark UI keep redirecting to /null and returns 500

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am having problem in accessing spark UI while running in spark-client mode. It works fine in local mode.

It keeps redirecting back to itself by adding /null at the end and ultimately run out of size limit for url and returns 500. Look at following below.

I have a feeling that I might be missing some config, I played with various config setting for yarn with no success.

I am using spark version 1.3.1

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
--2015-09-09 11:22:17--  http://192.168.13.37:4040/

Connecting to 192.168.13.37:4040... connected.

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 

  HTTP/1.1 302 Found

  Location: http://192.168.13.37:4040/null/

  Content-Length: 0

  Server: Jetty(8.y.z-SNAPSHOT)

Location: http://192.168.13.37:4040/null/ [following]

--2015-09-09 11:22:17--  http://192.168.13.37:4040/null/

Reusing existing connection to 192.168.13.37:4040.

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 

  HTTP/1.1 302 Found

  Location: http://192.168.13.37:4040/null/null/null/

  Content-Length: 0

  Server: Jetty(8.y.z-SNAPSHOT)

Location: http://192.168.13.37:4040/null/null/null/ [following]

--2015-09-09 11:22:17--  http://192.168.13.37:4040/null/null/null/

Reusing existing connection to 192.168.13.37:4040.

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 

  HTTP/1.1 302 Found

  Location:         http://192.168.13.37:4040/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/

  Content-Length: 0

  Server: Jetty(8.y.z-SNAPSHOT)

Location: http://192.168.13.37:4040/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/ [following]

--2015-09-09 11:22:17--      http://192.168.13.37:4040/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/

Reusing existing connection to 192.168.13.37:4040.

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 

  HTTP/1.1 302 Found

  Location: http://192.168.13.37:4040/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/

  Content-Length: 0

  Server: Jetty(8.y.z-SNAPSHOT)

Location: http://192.168.13.37:4040/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/ [following]

--2015-09-09 11:22:17--      http://192.168.13.37:4040/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/

Reusing existing connection to 192.168.13.37:4040.


Here is stack dump:

15/09/09 11:22:18 WARN server.Response: Committed before 500 null

15/09/09 11:22:18 WARN server.AbstractHttpConnection:     /null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/null/

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Committed

        at org.spark-    project.jetty.server.Response.resetBuffer(Response.java:1154)

        at org.spark-    project.jetty.server.Response.sendError(Response.java:317)

       at org.spark-project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1095)

    at org.spark-project.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)

    at org.spark-project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)

    at org.spark-project.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)

    at org.spark-project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)

    at org.spark-project.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)

    at org.spark-project.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)

    at org.spark-project.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)

    at org.spark-project.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)

    at org.spark-project.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)

    at org.spark-project.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)

    at org.spark-project.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)

    at org.spark-project.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)

    at org.spark-project.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:667)

    at org.spark-project.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)

    at org.spark-project.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)

    at org.spark-project.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Is it Standalone mode or Yarn Mode? And is your job running while you Open the 4040 URL?

Comment: Its in yarn mode.. and yes my job is running while I try to connect to UI.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it took me a long time to identify it and find a solution.

I was using spark in `yarn-client` mode against an EMR cluster and the jars in the driver's classpath didn't match the jars on the cluster, specifically **hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy.jar**. Bringing only EMR's jars from the cluster to the driver and adding only them to the driver's classpath solved it.